# UIActionSheet showInview method cause crashed the app in second time

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I am using UIActionSheet to choose options. The same code work fine in iOS 7 but the problem arise in iOS 8.

```
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose an option" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:Nil otherButtonTitles:@"Option1", @"Option2", @"Option2", nil];
```

On a IBAction I am using the below code  to show action sheet.

```
[actionSheet showInView:[self view]];
```

It's work fine for the first time. But in second time the app got crashed due to EXE_BAD_ACCESS 
[image]

Comment: try to release your UIActionSheet after every use or, the best option: use UIAlertController to replace all AlertView and ActionSheet in iOS8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspiring from `@TonyMkenu`'s comment I do below and it's work.

On completion of dismissViewControllerAnimated I released the action sheet.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        actionSheet =nil;
}];
```

And before calling I allocated the action sheet every time.

```
if(! actionSheet)
   actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose an option" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:Nil otherButtonTitles:@"Option1", @"Option2", @"Option2", nil];

[actionSheet showInView:[self view]];
```

Comment: You should use UIAlertController for ios8 now.

Answer (score 0):

If the code isn't in viewcontroller，you may just make the view's window always be keywindow.

```
 [actionSheet showInView:[self view]];
 [self.view.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score -2):

You should be using UIAlertController in iOS 8 as UIActionSheet and UIAlertView have been replaced by it. It's quite easy and make use of blocks. Here is a sample you can work with.

```
- (IBAction)actionButtonAction:(id)sender {
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Select an action" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    // These next two lines are necessary for iPad and wide layouts. 
    alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
    alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 34, 20, 0, 0);




    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Share Data" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        // Do action Share data
    }]];

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Share Plot" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        // Do action Share Plot
    }]];

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
         // User cancelled
    }]];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}
```