# Removing UIBlurView after Pop up controller is closed

Tags: ios, swift, popup, uiblureffect

I have a function that I call in the `viewDidLoad` of my `MainViewcontroller`

```
func showPopUp() {    

    self.popViewController = PopUpViewController(nibName: "PopUpViewController", bundle: nil)
    //self.popViewController.title = "This is a popup view"        

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    view.addSubview(blurEffectView)       

    self.popViewController.showInView(self.view, withImage: UIImage(named: "typpzDemo"), withMessage: "You just triggered a great popup window", animated: true)  
}
```

This brings up my `PopupViewController` and blurs the `MainViewController`. Inside my `PopupViewController` I have a `IBAction` to close this view controller

```
@IBAction func closePopup(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.removeAnimate()
   // Need to Close down the blur effect here!
    }
}
```

When I close the popup the main view controller is still blurred. How do I remove this blur view from inside the `closePopup` `IBAction`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `blurEffectView`once you have finished to use it. Inside the method `closePopUp` method try this :

```
blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Of course save a reference to this variable before, in the following way for example :

```
class PopUpViewController {

   var blurEffectView : UIVisualEffectView!

    @IBAction func closePopup(sender: AnyObject) {
       self.removeAnimate()
       blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

And before that you have to do it this :

```
func showPopUp() {    

    self.popViewController = PopUpViewController(nibName: "PopUpViewController", bundle: nil)
    //self.popViewController.title = "This is a popup view"        

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    view.addSubview(blurEffectView)       

    // In this line you pass the reference to the Blur
    self.popViewController.blurEffectView = blurEffectView


    self.popViewController.showInView(self.view, withImage: UIImage(named: "typpzDemo"), withMessage: "You just triggered a great popup window", animated: true)  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Victor! I thought it would be as easy as this... But now my question is how can I access blurEffectView in this other class?

Comment: @MattPorter I'm afraid it's another question , you can try this answer even to initialize before the View before show it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399167/uiactionsheet-showinview-method-cause-crashed-the-app-in-second-time

Comment: Its not really another question... This answer isn't complete.. Thanks for the starter anyway!

Comment: @MattPorter you have in your code a reference to the `PopUpViewController`, in which you can pass data before show it, create a variable like the `blurEffectView` and pass it before show the View

Comment: Thanks! I understand the concept now.. Apart from on  self.popViewController.blurEffectView = blurEffectView I get the error "Cannot assign to the result of this expression"

Comment: @MattPorter Sorry , my mistake `let` keyword is immutable change it to `var`  (`var blurEffectView : UIVisualEffectView!` )in declaration see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be how to communicate information between two ViewControllers. Although, there are a number of approaches you can take to this, I'll show you how to do it using the Observer Pattern with Foundation's `NotificationCenter`. In your `PopUpViewController`, add a Notification inside `closePopUp`:

```
    @IBAction func closePopup(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.removeAnimate()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(
            NSNotification(name: "popUpDidClose", object: self)
        )
    }
```

Back in your `MainViewController` add an Observer into your `viewDidLoad` method before firing off your `PopUpViewController`.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //...
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                selector: Selector("clearBlurEffect:"),
                name: "popUpDidClose",
                object: nil
        )
    }
```

Finally, add the method `clearBlurEffect` into `MainViewController`, which will correspond to the `selector` argument in `NSNotificationCenter`'s `addObserver` method. EDIT: You'll have to fire off the notification from the Main Queue.

```
    func clearBlurEffect(sender: NSNotification) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
            for subview in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
                if let v = subview as? UIVisualEffectView {
                    v.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, we dismiss any `UIVisualEffectView`'s from your main view.